# Using ArcPy dataSource Path with ArcSDE layers?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase

I have the following code:

When I run it:

```
conType = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(imxd, "Construction_pt", df)[0]
print conType.dataSource
prints... "Database Connections\Edit - Editor.sde\Edit.SDE.Construction_pt"
and rest of program runs correctly
```

When another user runs it:

```
print conType.dataSource
prints... "\Edit.SDE.Construction_pt"
program crashes because cannot find path
```

My question is why is it only displaying the full path for me and not other users?

ArcGIS 10,
Windows 7

Comment: Hard to tell like this. Maybe it is a `arcgis.workspace` problem. I ran into various problems not setting the `ArcInfoWorkspace()`. Even though this is under ArcGis 9x using the `gp`-object.

Comment: Have you tried using the CatalogPath method of the Describe object instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured out how to fix this:

In ArcCatalog, Database Connections, Select the SDE, and right click and go to Connection Properties.

Under Connection Details make sure the transactional version is set to that of the user (ex: "SDE.tom" and not the "SDE.default".

After changing this it now works correctly for the user who was having difficultly before.